# Use for-loop instead of repeating

Tags: objective-c, for-loop

Xcode noob here. Can anyone please guide me how to make list as below be done in for-loops? an if it possible? have it working with such lists but it takes too much time and can cause error due to repetition.

```
_monkey1.center = CGPointMake(_monkey1.center.x, _monkey1.center.y);
_monkey2.center = CGPointMake(_monkey2.center.x, _monkey2.center.y);
_monkey3.center = CGPointMake(_monkey3.center.x, _monkey3.center.y);
_monkey4.center = CGPointMake(_monkey4.center.x, _monkey4.center.y);
_monkey5.center = CGPointMake(_monkey5.center.x, _monkey5.center.y);
etc.
```

I have started with:

```
for (int k = 1; k < 20; k++){
// prep?
[[_monkeys objectAtIndex: k] setCenter: ....
}
```

Is there a possible way to do this? Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

monkeys are UIImageViews. Thanks.

Comment: Are _monkeyZ in a `NSArray`?

Comment: Then: `for (MonkeyClass *aMonkey in yourMonkeyArray){[aMonkey setCenter:ZzZ];}`?

Comment: You also nailed it mate. The bottom one just got more info.

Comment: Why would you set the center to be the center of the same object?

Comment: The x's and y's will have a random number added. At least this is the basic thing that needs to be repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *monkies = @[ _monkey1, _monkey2, _monkey3, _monkey4, _monkey5 ];
for (UIImageView *monkey in monkies) {
    monkey.center = CGPointMake(monkey.center.x, monkey.center.y);
}
```

(Note, I've assumed these objects are of type `Monkey`, which might be incorrect).

Comment: Monkeys are UIImageViews. I was about to ask you but preferred to at least solve that small issue by myself.

Answer (score 0):

There is an another way to achieve this:

```
for (int k = 1; k < 20; k++) {
    YourMonkeyClass *monkey = [self valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"monkey%ld", k]];
    monkey.center = CGPointMake(monkey.center.x, monkey.center.y);
}
```

for more details about `valueForKey:`, please refer to [Key-Value Coding and Observing](http://www.objc.io/issue-7/key-value-coding-and-observing.html).